# Manual mocks in Jest not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocking, jestjs

I would like to manually mock a function that makes a request to an external API. The function looks like this:

```
module.exports = function suggestions(token, query) {}
```

I created an `__mocks__/suggestions.js`  adjacent to the file which looks like:

```
module.exports = function suggestionsMock(token, query) {
   return [{id: 'a'}, {id: 'b' }]
}
```

In my test, I invoke:

```
jest.mock('../requests/suggestions')
const request = require('../requests/suggestions')

it('should call my request correctly', () => {
   //arrange and act
   //assert:
   expect(request).toHaveBeenCalled()
})
```

I keep getting the error:

```
jest.fn() value must be a mock function or spy.
Received:
  function: [Function mockSuggestions]
```

How does `jest.genMockFromModule` work if I export one function from a module instead of an object?